# What versions of GDM are used in Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 20.10, gdm

What versions of GDM are used in Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10? I found the version history of GDM: https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/
I need this to submit a bug on GDM's bugtracker

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdm

Comment: or for command line you can see package versions using `rmadison gdm3` and get the results without opening a browser...  (CLI tool includes ESM releases where the packages.ubuntu.com does not)